# How to call https url ajax request in java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can anybody tell How to call https url  ajax request in java script or jquery

is it possible to check iframe url is loaded or some error in server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "yoururl", // like url/methodname
    params : {Id : "1"} // pass data to method
    succss:function(){
        alert('Sucessfully');
    }
    error:function(error){
    alert('Error');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

and

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp

is probably what you are looking for, but you have to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "https://someurl"
    succss:function(){
        alert('Everything is OK');
    },
    error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```